# Cannot find -lalleg (DEV C++ e Allegro)

Tags: c, c++, dev-c++, allegro

Pessoal toda vez q tento rodar esse codigo está dando este erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o codigo abaixo:

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main() 
{   
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();

    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 800, 600, 0, 0);

    BITMAP *buffer = create_bitmap(800, 600);
    BITMAP *prota  = load_bmp("personaje.bmp",NULL);

    bool salir;
    int x,y;

    // inicializar vbles
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
    salir = false;

    while ( !salir )
    {   
          clear_to_color(buffer, 0xaaaaaa);

          masked_blit(prota, buffer, 0,0, x, y, 32,32);

          // teclas control usuario
          if ( key[KEY_UP] )
          {
               y--;
          }
          if ( key[KEY_DOWN] )
          {
               y++;
          }
          if ( key[KEY_LEFT] )
          {
               x--;
          }
          if ( key[KEY_RIGHT] )
          {
               x++;
          }                              

          // limites
          if ( x < 0 ) x = 0;
          if ( x > 800 ) x = 800;
          if ( y < 0 ) y = 0;
          if ( y > 600 ) y = 600;          


          blit(buffer, screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 800, 600);

          rest(10);

          // tecla de salida
          if ( key[KEY_ESC] ) salir = true;

    }  

    destroy_bitmap(prota);
    destroy_bitmap(buffer);

    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

Comment: Isso é allegro 4? Qual versão específica? Você colocou a DLL dele onde?

Comment: allegro 4.2, algo assim, dll?

Comment: dev C++ 4.9.9.2 e Allegro 4.2.2